# Identification: what type of connector does the pictured socket take?

Tags: connector

The picture was taken off an equipment we are trying to connect to. Unfortunately the connector type was not specified in user manual.

The closest one I can find based on shape is molex 4 pin female connector, or 4 pin peripheral connector used to send power to CD/hard drive in desktops.The difference is, molex connectors have flat sides, while the socket in picture has curves around each pin.

Could anyone offer some clue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pluggable terminal block. Probably something like [one of these](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Phoenix-Contact/1757048?qs=ibOxrZ%2Fd8eCneH3W48j9tg%3D%3D&gclid=Cj0KCQjwov3nBRDFARIsANgsdoGHOMx0iK-ubnRO0xFsi4PYbEiL0WfSkKN1iKPu0ZdoRG3kBeLspJgaAmMXEALw_wcB).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats a terminal block header probably the same one shown below:
[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-shore-technology-inc/OSTOQ045451/ED2830-ND/1588283

The terminal block plug can be found below

[image]
Source: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-shore-technology-inc/OSTTS04515A/ED2863-ND/1588621

Comment: Out of 3 different answers this answer shows the PCB mount and correct pin diam. +1 for being a good component Eng. with attention to details.

Comment: the actual component is more likely the following one judging from the two mounting holes:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/phoenix-contact/1776524/277-5771-ND/349002

Answer (score 5):

That is a Camdenboss CTBP9350/4 (or equivalent). The mating plugs are:

- CTBP9200/4
- CTBP92VG/4R

They are available from all major distributors (Farnell, RS, Digikey, Mouser, Arrow, etc..).

Comment: thank you so much.Have been searching for it the whole morning. Remember seeing them here or there, but the name always evades me.

Comment: My pleasure, we use a lot of them on control equipment. Customers love that you can wire them, then connect them. As opposed to standard screw-terminals which can be awkward.

Answer (score 4):

These connectors are most known from the **Phoenix Contact Combicon** family.
The shown socket mates with MSTB 2,5 HC/ 4-STF (1912090), however the metal plating inhibits the locking screws. So use MSTB 2,5 HC/ 4-ST (1911871).

That is assuming it's 5 mm. If it's 5.08 mm then add "-5.08".
*However with a 4 pin you can just use more force...*

Or get any of the other terminations they offer, they have a lot of choice. (eg: straight/angled or cage/spring)